# Python stdout.readline() freeze

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm using in my python script:

```
cmd = ["checkcode.exe", "code=1234"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close)
result = proc.stdout.readline()
```

checkcode.exe return a value, or nothing, and stay alive

All works fine when checkcode.exe return a value, but when checkcode.exe don't return value, the script block at result = proc.stdout.readline()

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: Is checkcode exiting? If it's not, your readline is waiting for that to happen so it can get an eof marker.

Comment: No, checkcode stay alive...

Comment: By 'return a value', do you mean 'writes a value to stdout'?  There is a difference between the two.  If `checkcode` stays alive, then it cannot return a value, so I assume you do mean that it either writes some data to stdout or it does not.  If it does not, then readline is blocked, waiting for some data.

Comment: Because it's possible that `checkcode` doesn't print anything, but also doesn't exit, it sounds like you're going to need to do a non-blocking read with a timeout. See this question for a way to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: checkcode stay alive, but proc.stdout.readline() return a value when checkcode return a value, instead it stay alive. proc.stdout.readline() block (waiting for some data) when checkcode don't return a value.

Comment: @MarcoT. Just to clarify, `checkcode.exe` runs, and sometimes prints something and sometimes doesn't. If you run `checkcode.exe` directly (meaning not via Python), does it exit after it prints (or doesn't print), or does it stay running forever? It's still not clear to me if the "`checkcode.exe` doesn't exit" behavior is expected or not.

Comment: +1 for @dano, I was just going to post that link!

Comment: checkcode.exe sometimes prints something sometimes doesn't, but in any case doesn't exit, it stay running forever.

Comment: The asyncproc module seem don't work on windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must ensure that the subprocess exits in order to prevent readline() from blocking. The readline waits until it receives a newline or end-of-file. EOF is achieved on program exit.

Alternatively, you can use non-blocking I/O as mentioned in the comment above.